# Is it possible to use "PackageReference" in Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS projects?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

By default, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects use a `package.config` file to manage Nuget dependencies. The Microsoft page about [Package references (PackageReference) in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) says:

> By default, PackageReference is used for .NET Core projects, .NET
>   Standard projects, and UWP projects targeting Windows 10 Build 15063
>   (Creators Update) and later. .NET full framework projects support
>   PackageReference, but currently default to packages.config. To use
>   PackageReference, migrate the dependencies from packages.config into
>   your project file, then remove packages.config.

I think this is not clear about the use of PackageReference style in Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS projects.

My question: is it possible to use PackageReference in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, `PackageReference` works for Xamarin.iOS|Android projects and in Visual Studio for Windows or Mac or via the cmd-line (nuget restore or via msbuild).

Add the following to the top of your `Xamarin.iOS` and/or `Xamarin.Android` `.csproj` file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

My current steps are:

- Copy your `packages.config` as a backup

  - Use it as a reference when you re-add the packages on the last step
- Manually remove all packages from the project (`Xamarin.iOS` or `Xamarin.Android`)
- Edit the csproj and add the `PackageReference`
- Re-add just the **top-level** packages

**Note**: I do the manual package remove one-by-one via the IDE in order to properly update the project references. Also, when re-adding them after the PackageReference additional, the csproj is updated correctly (you can do this manually in the csproj text but it is a pain and easy to screwup).

Comment: Hello @SushiHangover. Thank you for your answer. Is this approach compatible with Visual Studio for Mac? Sorry, I'm a newbie in the .NET world.

Comment: @BrunoPeres Yes, just updated answer, I do this mainly in VS4M as that is my prime development IDE (and of course if works in VSfW also).

Comment: thank you again! I upvoted your answer and now I will test your approach here. I will accept your answer as the right as soon as possible. :)

Comment: Thanks so much.  This works in a xamarin.mac project also.

Comment: Looks like we now have a feature `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference` if you right click on `References` in your project.  Worked for me in `VSfW2017 15.9.4 Preview 1.0` with a little hand cleanup

Comment: Migrate packages still not available for VS for Mac in late 2021 :-(