# Where to find package dependencies in Visual Studio For Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

When I add a nuget package like EntityFramework, where is the package listed? That is, what file? I thought it would be in my .csproj file but it does not seem to be. Package.json is of course gone.  I can see it listed in files in my bin and obj directories but those are temporary so I assume they must be someplace else also.

Comment: `config.package` is where your project packages are referenced for non-`PackageReference` based projects, you can always convert them to `PackageReference` if you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266856/4984832

Comment: What sort of project are you using?