# xamarin form: Where is the package.json in my solution

Tags: git, xamarin, package, repository

I have created the Xamarin .net standard solution which contains three main project .net Standard, Droid, and iOS. I tried to push these project to repository. The bin/obj if ignored in my push which I understand those folder will be regenerated when clean and rebuild.

I can see a package folder under the same directory as the solution file. It contains all the packages i have included in my projects.

Should I upload those packages in the packages folder? I can't see something similar like package.json file but can see file like 'project.assets.json' in obj folder under iOS project, Droid, and the main project.

Comment: .NetCore/.NetStd/.UWP/etc... are all supported now via `PackageReference` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266384/there-is-possible-to-use-packagereference-in-xamarin-android-or-xamarin-ios-pr/49266856#49266856 So the top-level package is contained within the `.csproj`

Answer (score 0):

in netstandard projects, [package references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) are stored directly in the project file.  You generally should not store packages in your repo, as they can always be retrieved from nuget (or another package source) when needed.